# PARTITION BY multiple column while inserting data from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-insert, greatest-n-per-group

How can I skip unique constraint error in SQL Server?

This is my source table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE source 
(
    RollNo INTEGER,
    Nam VARCHAR(6),
    Gender VARCHAR(1),
    Score INTEGER
);
    
INSERT INTO source (RollNo, Nam, Gender, Score)
VALUES ('101', 'John', 'M', '85'),
       ('102', 'Tracy', 'F', '79'),
       ('103', 'Jake', 'M', '92'),
       ('104', 'Edgar', 'M', NULL),
       ('105', 'Monica', 'F', '25'),
       ('106', 'Monica', 'F', '50'),
       ('1070', 'Yash', 'M', '68'),
       ('107', 'Yash', 'M', '70'),
       ('108', 'SFS', 'M', '68'),
       ('18', 'SFS77', 'F', '65');
```

I want populate in the `dest` table from `source` table where `name` & `Gender` is a Unique key and `SeqNo` should increment automatically:

`dest` table description:

```sql
CREATE TABLE dest 
(
    SeqNo BIGINT IDENTITY(1000,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    RollNo INTEGER,
    Nam VARCHAR(6),
    Gender VARCHAR(1),
    Score INTEGER
);
```

Here's what I tried:

Attempt #1:

```sql
INSERT INTO dest (RollNo, Nam, Gender, Score) 
    SELECT 
        FIRST_VALUE(RollNo) OVER (PARTITION BY Nam, Gender ORDER BY Score DESC),
        FIRST_VALUE(Nam) OVER (PARTITION BY Nam, Gender ORDER BY Score DESC),
        FIRST_VALUE(Gender) OVER (PARTITION BY Nam, Gender ORDER BY Score DESC),
        FIRST_VALUE(Score) OVER (PARTITION BY Nam, Gender ORDER BY Score DESC)
    FROM 
        source 
    WHERE 
        Nam IS NOT NULL AND Gender IS NOT NULL ;
```

> ERROR: Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint

Attempt #2:

```sql
INSERT INTO dest (RollNo, Nam, Gender, Score) 
    SELECT MAX(RollNo),Nam, Gender, MAX(Score) 
    FROM source
    GROUP BY Nam, Gender
    ORDER BY MAX(Score) DESC;
```

Output:

```
| SeqNo | RollNo |    Nam | Gender |  Score |
|-------|--------|--------|--------|--------|
|  1000 |    103 |   Jake |      M |     92 |
|  1001 |    101 |   John |      M |     85 |
|  1002 |    102 |  Tracy |      F |     79 |
|  1003 |   1070 |   Yash |      M |     70 |
|  1004 |    108 |    SFS |      M |     68 |
|  1005 |     18 |  SFS77 |      F |     65 |
|  1006 |    106 | Monica |      F |     50 |
|  1007 |    104 |  Edgar |      M | (null) |
```

If you see the row of yash it is taking max of RollNo. and max of Score which is wrong, I want it to take first value but I don't know how to do it.

Is there any other way to solve exclude this above two methods?

Comment: Days ago you were using MySQL. Are you really certain you are using SQL Server? Those have different syntax rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can identify the row that has the highest score for each Nam/Gender tuple with `ROW_NUMBER()`, and use that information to filter the source data:

```
INSERT INTO dest (RollNo, Nam, Gender, Score) 
SELECT RollNo, Nam, Gender, Score
FROM (
    SELECT s.*,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Nam, Gender ORDER BY Score DESC) rn
    FROM source s
) s
WHERE rn = 1
```

Side note: I would recommend putting a unique constraint on Nam/Gender tuples in the target table, so potential duplicates are always rejected at insert time:

```
CREATE TABLE dest (
  SeqNo  BIGINT IDENTITY(1000,1) PRIMARY KEY,
  RollNo INTEGER,
  Name   VARCHAR(6),
  Gender VARCHAR(1),
  Score  INTEGER,
  UNIQUE (Name, Gender)
);
```

Side note #2: don't put single quotes around column names; they stand for literal strings in standard SQL.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Actually I am new in SQL stuff. And it works as expected but I have to remove s.*. Can you explain me why? [http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/2a1ec/1](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/2a1ec/1)

Comment: @HarshitMahajan: the table alias was missing. Fixed.